Do Genshin Impact commissions system lock the player into evil achievements?
Some daily commissions in Genshin Impact include achievements that require the player acting quite toxic.

Pigeon, Duck, and Child can be completed by killing the ducks you were asked to feed. This ends up with Timmie getting mad at you  and a secret commission the next day that will give the player the achievement "Taking Responsibility for Your Actions"

In Food Delivery you can steal and eat the food you were supposed to deliver for the achievement "Get Your Own Emergency Food!"

In Good Sign you can ruin the signs that Zhihua is looking for and get the Open to Interpretation achievement. While the character is a stalker that keeps bothering a girl even after she called the guard on him multiple time ruining the signs still involves attacking dogs, a cat and killing some pigeons.

In The Taste of Home the player can give a "suspicious" quality food item to Tang Wen, resulting in her getting a stomachache and unlocking another secret commission called Absolutely Unique Delicacy which when completed gives out the Liyue Ichiban achievement

In This Novel Is Amazing you can open the sealed package you had to deliver and read the manuscript to get the achievement of the same name


These are just some examples but it should be pretty clear that these "achievement" you get for being evil fall in a weird scale.

for some you just have to be little more than a prankster
for some you have to be pretty abusive and do thinks like harassing an (orphan) kid, steal or give someone food poisoning
for some you have to go out of your way to attack or even kill creatures "for fun"

For these reasons some of these "awards" look more of a reminder of you giving up to Chara, a permanent reminder of you selling your soul to 100% completion. Not something every player is fine with.
Until some time ago it was possible to just avoid performing these actions whenever the affected commissions would rarely show up. You missed the ..1 gem award.. (a single pull costs 160...) but you kept your ideals.
Yet in patch 4.4 a breaking change was made.

If related achievements of a Commission Quest are not unlocked yet, the probability of that Commission Quest appearing will increase.

Sadly, the "increase" here basically means that the game will keep presenting you that commission and nothing (almost) else every single day, until you falter and cave in.
Should you for example set your region to Mondstadt  and missing "Taking Responsibility for Your Actions" the game will enter an endless Samsara not even Nahida can save you from, a groundhog day loop where every new day you will get "Pigeon, Duck, and Child"  again and again and again until you quit, move to a different region or just accept that you are required to be a bastard to move on.
The question is simple.
Can the player do anything to workaround the effect of this silly fix that didn't consider that you may be avoiding getting an achievement ON PURPOSE? Or are players now required to be evil and get evil awards to be able to play the game as intended?

"...even kill creatures "for fun"" ever tought about those abyss mages having a family as well? Or the fashionable Fatui Pyroslinger Bracers? They're humans as well. Picking that scarce endangered coral to lvl up your kokomi? You are already pretty evil!

@ChrᴉzremembersMonica oh, if you want some pretty nightmare fuel about the Abyss and mobs you fight, you don't have but to ask in chat. You just scratched the surface.

@ChrᴉzremembersMonica also technically Kokomi uses pearls. Want to talk instead about the Transoceanic Chunks everyone in Fontaine adores?
